# How i can find a elements with tag table in a html page

Tags: java, htmlunit

I have the html page, and me need find some elements with tag a 'table', but such tables maybe more than one, and they don't have id or class name.
Example:

```html
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
.....

<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
.....

<table>
<tbody> 
<tr>    <-------BINGO! 
.....
```

How i can it's do with help HtmlUnit?
Thanks...

Comment: Must it be done with HtmlUnit? Also, the element you point to isn't a table, but a table row.

Comment: I would use the String.split() function. If you give me the specific website, I can take a look for you. If there's anything unique before the stuff you need, String.split() will work. It will also work if there number of tables is the same.

Comment: @Ryan Thansk. Please look, this website [e1.ru](http://www.e1.ru/business/realty/search.php?s_obj_type=1&rq=1&op_type=1&city_id=1&region_id=0&area_all=-1&sb=21&ob=1&p=68)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`HtmlPage.getElementsByTagName("table")`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlPage.html#getElementsByTagName%28java.lang.String%29) and iterate over the returned list of HtmlTable objects until you find the table you want to find.